# What does "differentiate for" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does **differentiate for** mean?.

I looked it up in several online dictionaries such as Cambridge or oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com but all of them are about the meaning of *differentiate from* or *differentiate between*.

This is a context I found them:

> Utilising AI can be an easy way to personalise training to differentiate for things such as department and levels of ability

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like a bit of a mistake to me. If you simply remove *for* from that quote, it should result in what was intended. I also note that it should be *departments* (plural), so the author may have made an additional mistake with the use of *for*. Although I can see why somebody might use *for* (it's used in a fashion similar to its used with other verbs—doing something to fulfil a purpose), I don't think its as common as just omitting it with this verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the context here is computer engineering. Engineers often talk about their work in terms of math. I believe that 'differentiate' is being used in this case much like we use the word 'solve' in math.

> The question requires you to solve for the variable x

You can translate it loosely as 'create different results depending on differences in certain variables'.

> Utilising AI can be an easy way to personalize training to **create different training depending on differences in variables** such as department and levels of ability.

AI allows the trainer to make a different trainings that are appropriate for people in different departments and at different levels of ability.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to me